# Array of template class object

Tags: c++, templates, object, pointers

I'd like to make an array of multiple template objects.

For example, how to make an array filled with these 2 objects :

```
Foo< A, B, C > FooItem (bar_, bor_);
Foo < D, E, F > FooItem2 (bur_, ber_);

myArray[0] = FooItem;
myArray[1] = FooItem2;
```

Array of void* pointers ? Classical array ?

Thanks !

Comment: What the post shows is a function declaration. Where is the object?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Please try http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: `std::vector` and [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: @aleguna myArray[0] = FooItem; myArray[1] = FooItem2;

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean that you want an array that's able to hold objects of different types. A simple array can't do that since all elements must be of the same type, and `void*` wouldn't be much use since there would be no way to determine the type of any object, and therefore no way to do anything useful with them.

Various possibilities, depending on how you intend to use the objects in the array, include:

- Define a common base class, and store pointers to that. If the base class is polymorphic, you can use either virtual functions, `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` to interact with the objects.
- [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) can store an object from any of a predefined set of types. These can be stored in an array, are efficient (requiring no extra redirection) and can be accessed in a typesafe way without casts.
- [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) can store an object of any type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector of pairs:

```
std::vector< std::pair< Foo<A, B, C>, Foo<D, E, F> > > array;
```

If instead you want a plain data array:

```
std::pair< Foo<A, B, C>, Foo<D, E, F> > array[size];
```